# Native C++ passing IIterable to WinRT

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime, wrl

I have a Win32 app that is using WRL (Windows Runtime Template Library) to access the WinRT API.

How do I go about calling a function that takes an `IIterable` from native C++? My issue is obtaining something that implements `IIterable` or `IVector`.

As a concrete example, suppose I wanted to call `SetDefaultMenuItems` in Include\10.0.14393.0\winrt\windows.ui.input.h:

```
namespace ABI {
namespace Windows {
namespace UI {
namespace Input {

    MIDL_INTERFACE("A6B79ECB-6A52-4430-910C-56370A9D6B42")
    IRadialControllerConfiguration : public IInspectable
    {
        public:
            virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetDefaultMenuItems( 
            /* [in] */ __RPC__in_opt __FIIterable_1_Windows__CUI__CInput__CRadialControllerSystemMenuItemKind *buttons) = 0;
        // ...
    };
}
}
}
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a stock implementation of `IIterable` or `IVector` for native C++.

Comment: You could construct a [VectorView](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Runtime-Component-9b6c6989/sourcecode?fileId=113783&pathId=1623023906) over a `std::vector`, or any other appropriate container wrapper that matches your Standard C++ collection type.

Comment: I need to create a runtime component that implements IVectorView. I should then try to use that custom component to get the IIterable to pass to the API?

Comment: There is no `IVectorView` interface. `VectorView` is a class template, that implements the `IIterable` interface. You can immediately pass a pointer to a `VectorView` to a function expecting an `IIterable` interface. This really sounds like you are completely lost here, probably because you don't understand COM, C++, or how C++ is used to implement COM. And then WRL adds yet another abstraction that you need to master first. This is unlikely to end well. You'll have to start over and get familiar with the basics.

Comment: You're right I am new.

Comment: Adding updated link to VectorView implementation for future visitors: https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/master/source/uwp/Renderer/lib/Vector.h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [cppwinrt](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt) to do what I wanted. With this, I was able to pass vanilla std containers, etc. to WinRT.